# Where are the SQL development tools for the Eclipse IDE and Spring Tools Suite? Why are they seemingly unavailable in their marketplaces?

Tags: java, sql, spring, eclipse

I'm learning the Java Programming language and Spring, and when I try to follow some online tutorials or projects related to Spring technologies, I keep getting stuck whenever I need to create a new SQL file or a SQL database WITHIN the Eclipse IDE or Spring Tools Suite. I'm simply unable to do so, and while various solutions online simply give instructions to "search and install the SQL development tools or SQL editor from the Eclipse Marketplace", I am not able to find the SQL development tools, while the SQL editor is a very basic thing with no development facilities. So WHERE can I find the required tools/extensions for creating & running SQL files, databases, etc, on the Eclipse IDE or Spring Tools Suite? Also, are there any alternative extensions/add-ons that have the SQL development capabilities? I would be really grateful if someone could answer.

Comment: Help > Install New Software... Choose your current release in 'Work With' and them look at the Database Development section

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks a LOT sir. I found a whole bunch of Database Development tools, which also included a lot of SQL development tools, by following your approach!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit unsure if it is exactly what you're looking for, but Data Tools Platform is the one i've been using in the past to manage DBs:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-dtp-data-tools-platform

Comment: I'm actually looking for ANY SQL development tool that enables people to create & manage SQL databases WITHIN the Eclipse or STS IDE! Apparently, the most popular one used to be the "SQL Developer Tools" that was readily available via the Eclipse or STS marketplace search, but now, it seems to have vanished! The SQL Editor (returned as a search result) only helps in text-editing manually-created SQL files, and not creating/managing SQL databases. I'm stuck, as a result, on a LOT of tutorial projects & frankly, running out of valuable time to make them too! So if possible, please help!

Answer (score -1):

turnoff the firewall and then try to install it. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).